# ListView ordered by user and date

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have this view:

```
class IndexLatest(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'latest'
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'my_app/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user,)
```

How can I add the `order_by` argument to the queryset? The model has a date field, and I've tried to add it after the comma but it did not work out!

Answer (score 1):

You can [chain](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters) `filter()` and `order_by()` calls on a queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return MyModel.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user).order_by('-date')
```